# Flexbox image resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm new to using flexbox and I'm trying to create a portfolio page that has several different widths, heights and a slideshow in there as well. I just can't seem to get the images to stay the same height when resizing the page. The slideshow / largest image in the bottom section of the portfolio keeps decreasing in height. I need the height of the images to stay proportionate to one another regardless of the screen size. Just wondering what I am missing here. I've included the URL, rather than markup and recreating in jsfiddle.

http://keaadvertising.com/new/kea-advertising-portfolio.php

```
    /* Portfolio */
.portfolio { margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 1.5em .5em; 
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.portfolio li {
    padding: 0 .5em;
}
.portfolio li img { height: auto; }
.bottomPortfolio { padding-top: 0; }
.portfolio li .splitPortfolio li { padding: 0; }
.portfolio li .splitPortfolio li:first-of-type { padding: 0 0 .7em; }
.bottomPortfolio .firstPortfolio { flex: 1 1 15% }
.bottomPortfolio .secondPortfolio {flex: 1 1 16%; }
.bottomPortfolio .thirdPortfolio { flex: 3 3 49%; }
.bottomPortfolio .fourthPortfolio { flex: 1 1 16%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this adjustment:

```
.portfolio li img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;   /* NEW */
}
```

Comment: thanks @Michael_B but no go. I had that in my previous iteration, but the resize just causes the page to go crazy

Comment: I tested it on your web page and it worked fine. If you can reproduce the problem in a demo (e.g. jsfiddle.net), that may be useful.

Comment: the resizing does work, however if you look closely when resizing the bottom of the images do not align. I'm dealing with some very particular artists and they have to align perfectly... any other ideas. I can try to recreate in fiddle

Comment: I do see that. It's slightly shorter than the adjacent columns. The first column is also shorter. The parent of the `img` isn't accepting any `height` declaration. It appears there some JS or another slider script overriding `height`.

Comment: After some tweaking I was able to get this to work. What I did was added exact width percentages for each bottom portfolio. Thank you for jogging some things I wasn't thinking of before.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to try out widths for each bottom portfolio and it seemed to have resolve

```
.portfolio { margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 1.5em .5em; 
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.portfolio li {
    padding: 0 .25%
}
.portfolio li img { height: auto; width: 100%; }
.bottomPortfolio { padding-top: 0; }
.portfolio li .splitPortfolio li { padding: 0; }
.portfolio li .splitPortfolio li:first-of-type { padding: 0 0 .7em; }
.bottomPortfolio .firstPortfolio { width: 16.08%; }
.bottomPortfolio .secondPortfolio { width: 16.78%; }
.bottomPortfolio .thirdPortfolio { width: 50.82%; }
.bottomPortfolio .fourthPortfolio { width: 16.2%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a min-height that will make sure images don't reduce in height past a certain value.

So something like:

```
.potfolio li img {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

This should make it to where the image will size up infinitely, but will only size down to 200px.